# ¿como resuelvo este problema en Xamarin Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

cree un nuevo proyecto y al iniciar me salio este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien paso por esto ??

Comment: Parece que es un problema muy común. Intenta ir a la consola de Nuget y ejecuta el siguiente comando: `Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`

Comment: soy principiante, como encuentro la consola ?

Comment: `Herramientas/Administrador de paquetes NuGet/Consola del administrador de paquetes`